# Retrieve image from folder in server

Tags: c#, image, foreach, server, directory

```
private List<ImageUrl> GetImageNames()
{

    var mediaServerFilePath = Helper.GetMediaDomain();
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Split('/');
    var FolderName = path.Last().Replace(".htm", "");
    var languageCode = Helper.CurrencyCode;
    var images = mediaServerFilePath + "/Assets/img/DepositHelp/Banner" + "/" + languageCode + "/" + FolderName +"/"+ "*.jpg";
    List<ImageUrl> ImageUrlList = new List<ImageUrl>();
    foreach (var image in images)
    {

        ImageUrlList.Add(new ImageUrl { Name = mediaServerFilePath + "/Assets/img/DepositHelp/Banner" + "/" + languageCode + "/" + FolderName + "/" + image+".jpg" });
    }
}
```

I already given the path for the image but the result that it return is not the same name as the picture in the folder.

Is there any wrong with this code?

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: i expect it will get the picture folder and the name of the pcture

Comment: What are *the actual values* that you expect and that you are getting.

Comment: @Hunter if my answer helped you, [please mark it as accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

`var images` is a `String`, and `var image` is a `Char`. Your `foreach` is looping over all the single *characters in that path's string*, not over the files in that folder.

This means you are generating a new `ImageUrl` for every character in that path.

There is no code anywhere in that block that actually *retrieves* any files from that folder.

I strongly advise you to stop using `var`. It may seem like a handy shortcut, but it'll just end up confusing you. If you had just explicitly defined your variables, you would immediately have seen that this wasn't correct:

```
private List<ImageUrl> GetImageNames()
{
    String mediaServerFilePath = Helper.GetMediaDomain();
    String[] path = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Split('/');
    String FolderName = path.Last().Replace(".htm", "");
    String languageCode = Helper.CurrencyCode;
    String images = mediaServerFilePath + "/Assets/img/DepositHelp/Banner" + "/" + languageCode + "/" + FolderName + "/" + "*.jpg";
    List<ImageUrl> ImageUrlList = new List<ImageUrl>();
    foreach (Char image in images)
    {
        ImageUrlList.Add(new ImageUrl {Name = mediaServerFilePath + "/Assets/img/DepositHelp/Banner" + "/" + languageCode + "/" + FolderName + "/" + image + ".jpg"});
    }
}
```

As you see, the code is perfectly valid, but absolutely not what you had in mind.